# sql server float format globalization

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, numbers, format

How to make a general type (using period instead of comma) of float in SQL Server?

My SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) in Local Computer is showing number with comma (23,10). But when I try with my SSMS in server, it's showing number with period (23.10).

This affect when I try to insert a number.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ColumnA) VALUES (10.20)
```

It will insert 1020 instead of 10.20

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ColumnA) VALUES (@val)
```

and

```
double val = ... // or decimal, float, etc...
cmd.Parameters.Add("val", val);
```

then it ceases to be an issue.

If you want to use SQL literals, you need to use `.` as the decimal specifier. What SSMS shows you in *results* is UI-formatted (so: i18n/g10n). Raw TSQL input, however, does not obey such niceties. Neither does C#.

Comment: Yes, I use period. When I try to insert 10.20 (local computer), the SQL Server Database store it as 1020, which is wrong. But when I try it in server directly, it stores 10.20